# problem while update a foreign key value using criteria

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpql

While trying to update a foreign key value of my table 2, I get the below error and how to update a foreign key value using criteria queries.

User Entity class:

```
  @Entity
  public class User  {
        @Id 
        @Column(name="USER_ID")
        private int userId;
        @Column(name="USER_NAME")
        private String userName;
       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
       private Collection<Rooms>rooms  = new ArrayList<Rooms>();
    }
```

Rooms Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Rooms {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROOM_ID")
    private int roomId;
    @Column(name = "ROOM_NAME")
    private String RoomName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;
}
```

My update criteria query:

```
CriteriaBuilder connectionIdBuilder = roomSession.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<Rooms> criteriaUpdate = connectionIdBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(Rooms.class);
Root<Rooms> roomRoot = criteriaUpdate.from(Rooms.class);
Path<Integer> bId = roomRoot.join("user").get(SmatrEntityParameters.USER_ID);
     criteriaUpdate.where(connectionIdBuilder.equal(roomRoot.join("user").get(SmatrEntityParameters.USER_ID),userId));      
roomSession.createQuery(criteriaUpdate).executeUpdate();
```

**Error:update/delete criteria queries cannot define joins**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UPDATE/DELETE criteria queries cannot define joins
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.RootImpl.illegalJoin(RootImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractFromImpl.join(AbstractFromImpl.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractFromImpl.join(AbstractFromImpl.java:386)
    at com.sss.iot.smatr.util.CriteriaMethods.updatereference(CriteriaMethods.java:232)
```

Please give me suggestions on how I update a foreign key value i.e here userid using criteria queries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete delete entities from a joined table with JPA 2.1 CriteriaDelete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070249/how-to-delete-delete-entities-from-a-joined-table-with-jpa-2-1-criteriadelete)

Comment: it seems like but i want update query